# Java and MS sql server

Tags: java, sql-server

I am designed an android app using java and i would like to know is it possible for the app to connect to a MS sql server backend database to receive and write data ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Titles should be questions, or at least describe the subject of the question in sufficient detail.

Answer (score 0):

java can connect to SQL server, using MySQL-connector

download here:  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.1.html